# some guidance on my SSO implementation = setting up identity server and using it programmatically

Tags: .net, saml, identity

I need some guidance on my SSO implementation. We have a web application where we are authenticating the user through applications Database. We check user details in USER table and match password. If everything looks good we create .net session and allow user to Login. One of our partnersnrequested for SSO integration, they want us to behave like Identity Provider (their application will be Service Provider). I have no idea from where should I start. Few initial guiding points will be a great help.

Comment: Matching a password is **NEVER** okay. You should not store passwords for this purpose. Instead, the short version is you store a **hash** of the password; when someone tries to log in, you also hash the attempted password and compare the hashes. Anything less is a data breach waiting to happen. Please do more research on correct password handling before using this system... the design your described is **VERY BAD!**

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose an IDP e.g. Azure AD, Auth0, Okta, Shibboleth, identityserver 4 ...

Only a few IDP can authenticate against a SQL DB.

Have a look at Auth0 (paid) or identityserver 4 (free).

Both of these have client-side samples. These samples will use one of:

- WS-Federation
- SAML 2.0
- OpenID Connect

as the protocol to talk to your IDP. Use OIDC - it's the easiest - if you can.

Your partner will need to use one of these libraries in their application.